# Is there a way to set up an email notification when phpmyadmin table is updated

Tags: database, email, phpmyadmin, axios

I would just like to know if there is a way to receive email notifications when the database from phpmyadmin is updated. This is because my website has an axios .post method which sends all the needed information into the database and fills it up. But, I would to receive emails or notifications whenever they are updated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is the database, not phpmyadmin.

MySQL has no way to send emails, nor to perform any other external task.

You could write a cron job to poll the database periodically and issue the emails when it finds something.